# Cannot run netbeans IDE After Adding python plug in

Tags: jython, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I added this [plug in](https://techknowhow.library.emory.edu/blogs/sturnbu/2011/05/12/netbeans-7-and-python-ide) to my netbeans 7.2 IDE. Then, when I restarted the program and tried to open it again it did not open

as shown in this picture

[image: NetBeans loading page]

I tried to restore my Windows system to previous restore point but the problem still exist.

any ideas how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the repository that they advised you to adding in the your Netbeans install.

But really has reference to many more plugins and features installed, 
if you add this repository after upgrade the NetBeansIDE you ​​will see that all base modules **will have replaced by the development release** and practically you will have another version of netbeans installed.

I advise you to uninstall your current netbeans without deleting your workspace and reinstall your netbeans downloaded directly from the official website.

> *And also I would advise you in the future should try the unofficial plugin in a test environment. before bringing in your work
>   environment*

Comment: thank you, this seems the only solution.this is sad based on the fact that I need to deal with python in Netbeans platform to invoke python method inside java application. Any way thanks again for your explanation and the valuable advice :)